# leaning left tree + symbol table

Tags: java, c, algorithm

I want to implement a leaning left red black tree  + symbol table in C as in the books of Sedgwick. But I can't find more explanations on this subject. Anyone have some code for me to study it or text on the subject?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sedgewick himself has [implemented](https://gist.github.com/rkapsi/741080) this data structure; the link goes to code extracted from [this talk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/LLRB/LLRB.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! But have some implementation in C?

Comment: @Tisp Sedgewick's Java is basically not object-oriented, so the language shouldn't matter for learning purposes. Nevertheless, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-leaning_red–black_tree) collects some other implementations, including a couple in C.